# Problem with monitor resolution in Capybara object identification

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

When I run on a 15″ monitor, capybara is not able to click on a specific menu item, but when I run on a 29″ monitor, the test works perfectly.

How to adjust this in a way that the test runs regardless of monitor size?

I am using the following configuration:

```
Capybara.default_driver = driver
   Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 30
   Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(1366, 768)
   Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the window to `width: 2000, height: 2000` and see if works.

Or Your element might not be visible to click. So, you can add to scroll to that element and click it

For that, add a separate method like below

```
def scroll_to_css(css_selector)
  script = "document.querySelector('#{css_selector}').scrollIntoView(true);"
  Capybara.current_session.evaluate_script(script)
end
```

And call before clicking the element ex: `scroll_to_css ".css_selector"`